# How can a property class can call a method for its 'parent' class in Java?

Tags: java, android, events

I'm developing an Android application.

I have an activity `parentActivity` and a `subclass` for some tasks.

I also have a hidden textView in `parentActivity`. I want to show this textView from subclass, but I don't know how to do that.

I think I can call a `parentActivity` method from `subclass`. How can I do that?

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity
{
   private SomeClass mSomeClass;

   ...
}
```

I want to call `ParentActivity` from `mSomeClass`.

In C# I use event listener to do that.

I you need more details tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confused about what subclasses are. How about you show us some code.

Comment: @Falmarri: I've just added an example. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ParentActivity remains same

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity
{
   private SomeClass mSomeClass;
}
```

Small change in your SomeClass is required

```
class SomeClass extends XYZ
{
    ParentActivity parent;        

    SomeClass(ParentActivity p)   //Constructor
    {
       this.parent = p;
       ......
    }

    public void someMethodWhereParentAccessIsRequired()
    {
        .....
        parent.doSomethingOnSomeTextView();
        ....
    }

}
```

Finally, when you initialize mSomeClass inside ParentActivity:

```
mSomeClass = new SomeClass(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only call methods directly in ParentActivity from SomeClass if SomeClass is a non static inner class of ParentActivity.

```
public class ParentActivity {

  protected void parentActivityMethod() {
    System.out.println( "Method called" );
  }

  protected class InnerSomeClass { // This could extend SomeClass
    protected void callParentMethod() {
      parentActivityMethod();
    }
    // Maybe override SomeClass methods to invoke ParentActivity methods?
  }

  private InnerSomeClass someClass;

  public ParentActivity() {
    this.someClass = new InnerSomeClass();

    someClass.callParentMethod(); // Will print "Method called"
  }


}
```

This requires that `someClass` is instantiated within `ParentActivity`.

Alternatively, when you instantiate your SomeClass object you could pass a reference to the ParentActivity object. This also requires that you edit the SomeClass definition.

---

Original answer (no longer applies):

You can call methods of the super class via the `super` keyword.

A brief example:

```
public class Parent {
  protected String s1;
  protected void m1() {
    System.out.println( "PARENT M1" );
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

  protected void m1() {
    System.out.println( "CHILD M1" );
  }

  public String doSomething() {
    super.m1(); // Prints PARENT M1
    m1(); // Prints CHILD M1

    return s1; // Same as super.s1 because s1 has not been redeclared

  }

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    new Child().doSomething();
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained very well. I've just added an example to my question.

Answer (score 1):

`mSomeClass` is not a "subactivity" of `ParentActivity`. mSomeClass knows absoutely nothing about what classes "contain" it. This is a pretty clear indication that your design is severely flawed. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: mSomeClass is a OpenGL renderer that uses C++ to render something. From C++ I can call a method from mSomeClass, but I need to call a method from parentActivity to show a TextView.

Comment: My answer depends on the fact that you can't change mSomeClass. If you're the one making mSomeClass and can change the constructor, you can do as @Sarwar suggests and pass a pointer to your parentclass. Just be careful of storing references to Contexts as this could cause a memory leak. There is, however, no GENERAL way of calling methods in objects that contain that particular object.

Comment: and what about listerners? http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/

Comment: It depends what your classes are. There's lots of ways to make it possible to communicate between objects. But it really has nothing to do with Parent/Sub activities and it totally depends on what you want to do.